# error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘ObjectP’ in c - CIRCULAR DEPENDENCY

Tags: c, struct

I've written a little header file, and I keep getting this error:

```
expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘ObjectP’
```

I've been looking for an answer and I understand that it's because of the way the compiler parses the text. `ObjectP` is defined in `GenericHashTable.h` which is included as you can see. I've tried writing the `#include` AFTER defining the struct, didn't help. Here's the problematic code with error line marked:

```
#include "GenericHashTable.h"

typedef struct List* ListP;
typedef struct List
{
    unsigned int size;
    ObjectP head; <----- ERROR HERE
} List;
```

Any ideas? thanks!

EDIT: I think I know where the problem is. "List.h" includes "GenericHashMap.h" and vice versa, so I have kind of a circular dependency. When I remove the #include statement from one of them it compiles OK and the other one gets the error message.

Must I somehow break this circle, or is there another solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of this solution, since I do not see your `GenericHashTable.h`. But It would help if you make the definition of `ObjectP` in another header file which is included by your `GenericHashTable.h` and your header defining the list.